# How do I append duplicated records that share the same unique identifier?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

How do I append the address columns below into one? They share the same unique identifier, but are duplicated because it basically opens multiple rooms.

```
KeyID | KeyName | Room
00001 | 452-BF  | A-206
00001 | 452-BF  | A-207
00001 | 452-BF  | A-208
```

Here's my sql:

```
Select
k.keyid,
k.keyname,
r.room
from key k
join room r
on k.keyid = r.keyid
;
```

How do I format my slq so that I get the following results:

```
KeyID | KeyName | Room
00001 | 452-BF  | A-206,A-207,A-208
```

Also I'm on the 12c version of oracle sql(12.1.0.2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `listagg()`:

```
Select k.keyid, k.keyname,
       listagg(r.room, ',') within group (order by r.room) as rooms
from key k join
     room r
     on k.keyid = r.keyid
group by k.keyid, k.keyname;
```